# calling websocket send function from within .then() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, promise

i have a promise that resolves a JSON object with some config data. i want to access this data upon pressing the "send config" button in my HTML client. the communication is done through a websocket connection in nodejs. so the websocket server receives a message that says "send config" from the client and the server is supposed to respond with the config.

### code:

```
  showMsg = function (MSGOBJ) { 
            var parsedOBJ = JSON.parse(MSGOBJ);

            //console.log(parsedOBJ.content);
            for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
            switch(parsedOBJ.type) {
      case "text":
         console.log("Received: " + parsedOBJ.content)

         connections[i].sendUTF('{ "type":"text", "content":"Server ready."}')
         break;

      case "config":
   
         console.log("Received:1 " + parsedOBJ.content)          
         console.log("Sending config" )

         var getConfig = KRequests.getKConfig;

         var configOBJ;

         getConfig.then(function(result) {
            configOBJ = result
         });

         connections[i].send('{ "type":"config", "content":'+JSON.stringify(configOBJ)+'}');

         break; 
        }
     }
 }
```

i know configOBJ would be undefined if i use it outside of the chain, but just to give you an idea of what i want to do. and also if i move the send() inside the chain, it would cause this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issue one is that you should use:

```
getConfig.then(function(result) {
  console.log(connections[i])
  connections[i].send('{ "type":"config", "content":'+JSON.stringify(configOBJ)+'}');
});
```

The other is that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
```

should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
```

Or if you don't have `let` which you should if you are using a recent node that supports more than ES5. You will have to use a IIFE like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    // put the loop body here
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: when i put the send() function before i modified the loop to "let i" inside my chain it would give me this error  "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined". can you help me understand what made the difference? thanks

Comment: See [Understanding let and const in JavaScript ES6](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascript-es6-let-const.shtml)